# Echo effect to audio sound using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I am developing one audio processing utility in Qt(C++). I can hear audio from speaker when I speak through mike using my qt code. I need to apply echo effect to this audio output. In my code I am receiving audio using  a 16 bit byte array. 
How I can apply echo effect to this sound sample.

Comment: Three closevotes but only one downvote? o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to make an echo is to play the sound twice, near-simultaneously, with a slight delay between the two instances.  You might also make the volume of the second instance a bit less than the first instance.

You can do this by either mixing the sample stream together with itself (with an offset) and then playing the result, or possibly by creating two QAudioOutput devices and playing the sound in both of them (I haven't tried the latter though, so I don't know for sure if it would work)

Comment: How I can create a new sample buffer with a delay, suppose m_input is a QByteArray holds integer samples

Comment: Use a fixed-size FIFO queue of sample values as a "delay line".  For each sample in m_input, append that sample (perhaps divided by two to make the echo quieter than the original sound) to the end of the FIFO queue.  Then, if the queue's length has reached its maximum size M, pop a value off the head of the queue and add it to your sample in m_input.   (Choose M based on how long you want the echo to be... larger values simulate longer echoes)